# Cassandra - com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store

I am having the following persistent error in Cassandra:

Cassandra- All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: xxxxxx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections))))

The problem occurs while I am trying to load a large database into a single cluster. So far I have tried all the recommendations I found regarding this issue:

- I have only one cluster and one session
- I am using a prepared statement for insertions
- I have generously increased the the timeouts from both sides

I am pasting here the function I am using to load following the recommendations in this [blog post](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/), maybe someone can spot something. Changing the BATCH_SIZE , was the only factor which improved somehow the situation. If I set it in 1_000_000 it fails almost immediately, If I set it to 100_000 It runs for quite some time. In the code below pstatement is a PreparedStatement and futures is a 
List < ResultSetFuture >

.

```
public boolean addPair(byte[] key, byte[] value) throws IOException {
    if (futures.size() >= BATCH_SIZE) {
      flush();
    }
    BoundStatement boundStatementInsert = new BoundStatement(pstatement);
    futures
           .add(session.executeAsync(boundStatementInsert.bind(ByteBuffer.wrap(key), ByteBuffer.wrap(value)).setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL)));
    return true; }


private void flush() {
    for (ResultSetFuture rsf : futures) {
      rsf.getUninterruptibly();
    }
    futures.clear(); }
```

thanks in advance

Altober

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver won't handle more than a maximum number of requests to a given host simultaneously. This number depends on your pooling configuration, see details [here](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/features/pooling/) (use the combo in the top-left corner to match your driver version).

If you try to send more requests, they will queue up. The message `Timeout while trying to acquire available connection` indicates that queued up requests are timing out, in other words you're sending more than the driver can handle.

With the driver defaults the maximum should be 1024. That's very conservative, given the setup you describe I think you can go higher. Try adding more connections and/or raising the number of requests per connections, adjusting `BATCH_SIZE` accordingly.

Comment: The link to the details is obsolete.

Comment: nvm, here is the working one : https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.x/manual/pooling

Answer (score -3):

Batches are the best way to update/insert  multiple tables at once. Batches should be  small, under 5 kb of data. Batches are for atomicity, not performance optimization . Please refer https:// medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e  for faster Data Insert and it does not use Batch Statement